# Wait for an executable to finish with a cancellation support

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, thread-safety

I'd like to wait for an executable to finish but supporting a cancellation token at the same time. Most of the answers on SO suggest using process.WaitForExit but that does not support a cancellation token. What would be the best reliable way to go about this?

Below is my attempt using wait handles:

```
void Main()
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(/*1000*/))
    {
        string output = RunAndGetOutput("netstat", null, cts.Token.WaitHandle);

        if (output == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        else if (output.Length == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Didn't read anything..!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}

string RunAndGetOutput(string execName, string arguments, WaitHandle waitableHandle)
{
    using (Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = execName,
            Arguments = arguments ?? string.Empty,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        }
    })
    {
        bool processReallyExited = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Data == null) return;
            sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        };
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Data == null) return;
            sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        };
        process.Exited += (sender, args) => processReallyExited = true;

        try
        {
            bool result = process.Start();
            if (!result) return null;
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            if (!IsWaitable(waitableHandle))
            {
                // If a wait handle was passed but is closed, then don't wait
                if (IsClosed(waitableHandle)) return null;
                process.WaitForExit();
                return sb.ToString();
            }

            SafeWaitHandle waitHandle = null;
            ManualResetEvent processFinishedEvent = null;

            try
            {
                waitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);
                processFinishedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false) { SafeWaitHandle = waitHandle };

                WaitHandle[] waitHandles =
                {
                    processFinishedEvent,
                    waitableHandle
                };

                // delay the operation to test timeout
                // Thread.Sleep(1000);

                int ndx = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
                if (ndx != 0) return null;

                if (!processReallyExited && !process.HasExited)
                {
                    // Process didn't raise exit event! Make another attempt to wait for 0.5 second
                    if (!process.WaitForExit(500)) ndx = -1;
                }

                return ndx != 0 ? null : sb.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                processFinishedEvent?.Dispose();
                processFinishedEvent = null;
                waitHandle?.Dispose();
                waitHandle = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
}

bool IsWaitable(WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    return waitHandle != null && waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle != null && !waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle.IsInvalid && !waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed;
}

bool IsClosed(WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    return waitHandle != null && waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle != null && waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed;
}
```

Would this be a reliable way?

** I intend to use this with multi-threads.

Edit 1: Is using wait handles a reliable way? because if I used another command, for example, "cmd" and an argument like "/C dir", sometimes I don't get output although it was not timed out! It seems as if the executable has already exited before catching the wait handle or something.

Edit 2:
I think to demonstrate the problem better, threads must be involved in this code. So, I prepared an example with threads as simple as it gets with sample outputs.

I applologize if it's too long

```
void Main()
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(/*1000*/))
    {
        int n = 0;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
        {
            (threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
            {
                string output = RunAndGetOutput("cmd", "/C dir", cts.Token.WaitHandle);
                Interlocked.Add(ref n, 1);

                if (output == null)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task {n}:\nError");
                else if (output.Length == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task {n}:\nDidn't read anything..!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task {n}:\n" + output);
            })).Start();
        }

        // block until all threads finish
        foreach (Thread thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
}

static string RunAndGetOutput(string execName, string arguments, WaitHandle waitableHandle)
{
    using (Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = execName,
            Arguments = arguments ?? string.Empty,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        }
    })
    {
        bool processReallyExited = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Data == null) return;
            sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        };
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Data == null) return;
            sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        };
        process.Exited += (sender, args) => processReallyExited = true;

        try
        {
            bool result = process.Start();
            if (!result) return null;
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            if (!IsWaitable(waitableHandle))
            {
                // If a wait handle was passed but is closed, then don't wait
                if (IsClosed(waitableHandle)) return null;
                process.WaitForExit();
                return sb.ToString();
            }

            SafeWaitHandle waitHandle = null;
            ManualResetEvent processFinishedEvent = null;

            try
            {
                waitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);
                processFinishedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false) { SafeWaitHandle = waitHandle };

                WaitHandle[] waitHandles =
                {
                    processFinishedEvent,
                    waitableHandle
                };

                // delay the operation to test timeout
                // Thread.Sleep(1000);

                int ndx = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
                if (ndx != 0) return null;

                if (!processReallyExited && !process.HasExited)
                {
                    // Process didn't raise exit event! Make another attempt to wait for 0.5 second
                    if (!process.WaitForExit(500)) ndx = -1;
                }

                return ndx != 0 ? null : sb.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                processFinishedEvent?.Dispose();
                processFinishedEvent = null;
                waitHandle?.Dispose();
                waitHandle = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
}

static bool IsWaitable(WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    return waitHandle != null && waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle != null && !waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle.IsInvalid && !waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed;
}

static bool IsClosed(WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    return waitHandle != null && waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle != null && waitHandle.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed;
}
```

The output sometimes doesn't come, other times incomplete and other times I get all the output. This is unreliable though and I'd like to understand why is this happening.

---

Sample output:

1st attempt:

---

Task 1:

Didn't read anything..!

Task 2:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

Task 3:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

Task 4:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

Task 5:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

Task 6:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

Task 7:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

Task 8:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,095,296 bytes free
```

2nd attempt:

---

Task 1:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

Task 2:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 3:

Didn't read anything..!

Task 4:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 5:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 6:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 7:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 8:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

3rd attempt:

---

Task 1:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Task 2:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

Task 3:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 4:

Didn't read anything..!

Task 5:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 6:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 7:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config

2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Task 8:

Volume in drive C is OS

Volume Serial Number is DCFD-FBFC

Directory of C:\Program Files\LINQPad

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              .

2018-03-02  02:09 PM              ..

2018-02-19  03:48 AM        32,099,328 LINQPad.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 LINQPad.exe.config

2018-02-19  03:48 AM               400 lprun readme.txt

2018-02-19  03:48 AM            11,448 lprun.exe

2018-02-19  03:48 AM             2,814 lprun.exe.config
2018-02-19  04:21 PM                79 Readme.txt

```
           6 File(s)     32,116,883 bytes

           2 Dir(s)  56,503,042,048 bytes free
```

Comment: Is the executable code running from the Process one you are writing in c#?

Comment: Not always. might be an external command

Comment: You present code uses Process class with the communications using Standard Input and Standard output which doesn't support CancellationTokenSource.  The fix would be to use a stream class that support the CancellationTokenSource in place of Standard Input/Output. But you are now saying it may be an external command.

Comment: I used netstat which is not c#. Besides, StandardOutput has a BaseStream but I don't see how does this relate to waiting for the process to exit and possibly cancel the operation, WaitForExit - not to cancel the output gathering because I can kill the process if it was timed out?

Comment: The point is, is using wait handles a reliable way to wait for a process to exit? because if so, I can combine the process handle with the CancelationToken.WaitHandle and wait for any of them. But I'm not sure it's a reliable way because sometimes I don't get any output in the string although the operation was not timed out!

Comment: The app could be closing the stream without send a message.  Net stat is for IP connections and Standard Input/Output doesn't use IP. It is a tunnel through the windows operating system.

Comment: I tried a different command like cmd with args /C dir for example. The stream is not closed but the method WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles); returns with the value 0 which means the process exited normally but sometimes the output in StringBuilder sb is empty. I say sometimes because sometimes I get output and sometimes not. it happens randomly.

Comment: I just used netstat because it takes a while for it to finish execution, maybe close to 10 seconds or so. but any other command that runs fast will randomly give output and sometimes not which is strange!

Comment: Windows programs exit when there are not errors with exit(0) so that is why you are getting zero.If the program doesn't finish then you are reading the end of a stream if you are using a non blocking method.  If you are using a blocking method then you are probably getting a timeout.  You are only waiting .5 seconds for exit. process.WaitForExit(500)  Here is source : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,f8b2e604d6f1fe04

Comment: Hi again, Thanks. I just wanted to clarify something. I'm waiting for the program twice. The second wait is not the actual waiting. It's just a check in case I didn't receive the exit event. The waiting happens in int ndx = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);

The error I'm talking about happens under pressure when there are many calls to an external executable. I think I'd better put an actual code with a thread. I just wanted the code to be as simple as possible but apparently, I need to include a sample of threads involved. Thank you for your reply. I'll update soon when possible

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with an example involving threads and sample output to better demonstrate the problem. Thanks